# Error creating the package: cannot create directory ‘/opt/simplest_studio’

Tags: packaging

I trying to create a .deb package.
Created the control and rules files, did everything,
as it was said in the instructions and after a ten thousandth attempt
errors still pop up.
The $(MAKE) command is executed successfully and is created
a binary file, but then something strange happens.
For example, an attempt in the process of the '$(MAKE) install' command try to
create the '/opt/simplest_studio’ directory. I don't understand anything,
where does this come from. I.e. instead of putting the binary in a folder
the usr/bin that I specify, it tries for some reason
install it in the opt folder.
Then it is not clear how I can set in the rules file installing the icon and shortcut to launch the application,I tried to find examples with installing a shortcut and icon, I can't find...
Tell me what to do with all this heap of problems?

Here is the terminal output with the error:

```
helg@helg-VirtualBox:~/Create DEB/simplest-studio-1.1$ dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -rfakeroot
.
.
/usr/bin/make install DESTDIR=/home/helg/Create DEB/simplest-studio-1.1/debian/simplest-studio/usr/bin 
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/helg/Create DEB/simplest-studio-1.1'
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/simplest_studio’: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1075: install_target] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/helg/Create DEB/simplest-studio-1.1'
make: *** [debian/rules:23: install] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
```

rules file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE = 1

build:
    $(MAKE)
    #docbook-to-man debian/packagename.sgml > packagename.1

clean:
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    rm -f build-stamp configure-stamp
    $(MAKE) clean
    dh_clean

install: build
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_prep
    dh_installdirs
    # Add here commands to install the package into debian/package
    $(MAKE) install DESTDIR=$(CURDIR)/debian/simplest-studio/usr/bin 

# Build architecture -independent files here.
# binary-indep: build install

# Build architecture -dependent files here.
binary-arch: build install
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_installchangelogs
    dh_installdocs
    dh_installexamples
    dh_install
    dh_installman
    dh_link
    dh_strip
    dh_compress
    dh_fixperms
    dh_installdeb
    dh_shlibdeps
    dh_gencontrol
    dh_md5sums
    dh_builddeb

binary: binary-indep binary-arch
.PHONY: build clean binary-indep binary-arch binary install configure
```

Comment: Do you have a link to repository or you may share the `Makefile`? The path could be hard-coded in there.

Comment: It's already working. Thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear that, It would be good if you have an answer for it if you could put one, So we may learn from it. Otherwise we close the question.

Comment: Yes, close it, because I created the Rules file incorrectly myself.